# Qt 5.5 - Touch/multitouch not working with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, touch

I am trying to create a Qt Widgets application that supports multitouch. I am using a tablet with Ubuntu 14.04, QtCreator 3.5.0 and Qt 5.5.0 installed. I am compiling straight on the tablet.

I tried compiling some of the Qt Quick and Qt Widgets examples like [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-demos-photosurface-example.html), [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-touchinteraction-example.html) and [this one](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-gestures-imagegestures-example.html). All of them compiled well and all of them supported mouse and single-touch events but none supported multi-touch.

I tried modifying the source code of the last of the examples like this:

```
bool ImageWidget::event(QEvent *event)
{
    std::cout << GetEvent(event).toStdString() << std::endl;
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Gesture)
        return gestureEvent(static_cast<QGestureEvent*>(event));
    return QWidget::event(event);
}

QString ImageWidget::GetEvent(const QEvent * ev) {
   static int eventEnumIndex = QEvent::staticMetaObject
         .indexOfEnumerator("Type");
   QString result;
   result.append("QEvent");
   if (ev) {
      QString name = QEvent::staticMetaObject
            .enumerator(eventEnumIndex).valueToKey(ev->type());
      if (!name.isEmpty()) result.append(name); else result.append(ev->type());
   } else {
      result.append( "foo");
   }
   return result;
}
```

And all the output I get when I try to touch drag an item are sort of mouse events:

```
QEventMouseButtonPress
QEventMouseMove
QEventMouseMove
QEventMouseMove
QEventMouseMove
QEventMouseMove
QEventMouseMove
QEventMouseButtonRelease
QEventLeave
```

Other applications (like Google Chrome or Ubuntu itself) handle multitouch fine, so I guess it has something to do with Qt.

XInput states this about the currently installed versions:

```
xinput version 1.6.1
XI version on server: 2.3
```

I am relatively new to Qt and Ubuntu in general, so the problem could actually be pretty simple, but googling gave me no results. Thanks for your help in advance.

**UPDATE**

Also, I'd appreciate if someone shared the experience of using touch with Qt on Ubuntu or other Linux-based distros so that I could figure out whether it is a bug in OS or has something to do with hardware.

Comment: What gesture are you using? AFAIK, pinch resize is not supported in Ubuntu, but I may be wrong

Comment: @marmistrz I tried pinch and rotate. I also know pinch does actually work in google chrome, for instance.

Comment: I had experience with multitouch screens and qt quick based application on Fedora 19. I didn't has problems and configurations, all works from box. But, I was not handled special multitouch events.

Comment: Also, may be this topic will help you - https://forum.qt.io/topic/25102/multitouch-in-linux/3

Comment: I noticed some serious regressions in Qt 5.5, for now my work is stuck on 5.4 until those new bugs are fixed, hopefully in a year or two,,,

Answer (score 0):

To implement multi touch on single widget , we need to different events rather than QEventMouseButtonPress etc. 
There are new events types like TouchBegin , TouchUpdate , TouchEnd and new TouchEventsClass.

For better understanding follow link http://www.slideshare.net/qtbynokia/using-multitouch-and-gestures-with-qt